# Moving a specific value to the end of a randomly populated array

Tags: arrays, ruby, blackjack

I am creating a blackjack scoring method and I'm trying to move the Ace(s) to the end of the array in order to count it last. How would I do this? Because this is not working

```
if hand.include?("Ace") 
  hand.map{ |card| hand.last(card) if card == "Ace" }
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches work. One is to sort them to the end:

```
hand = %w[ 2 9 4 Q 3 2 A T J 6 ]

hand.sort_by { |v| v == 'A' ? 1 : 0 }
# => ["6", "9", "4", "Q", "3", "2", "2", "T", "J", "A"]
```

Another is to [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) like this:

```
hand.partition { |v| v != 'A' }.flatten
# => ["2", "9", "4", "Q", "3", "2", "T", "J", "6", "A"]
```

If you had a proper `Card` class that implemented something like `ace?` then this is even easier:

```
hand.partition(&:ace?).reverse.flatten
```

You could also make it so that an `A` sorts as 11, so it ends up last, as in:

```
CARD_SORT_VALUE = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k.to_i }.merge(
  'J' => 10,
  'Q' => 10,
  'K' => 10,
  'A' => 11
).freeze
```

Where you can use that to sort, like:

```
hand.sort_by { |c| CARD_SORT_VALUE[c] }
```

Again, even better if you have a `Card` class that implements [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Comparable.html) and has a `<=>` method to allow for sorting as in `cards.sort` just works.

If you want to solve the general problem of "what value(s) does this hand have" consider defining values as an array, as in:

```
CARD_VALUE = {
  '2' => [ 2 ],
  '3' => [ 3 ],
  '4' => [ 4 ],
  '5' => [ 5 ],
  '6' => [ 6 ],
  '7' => [ 7 ],
  '8' => [ 8 ],
  '9' => [ 9 ],
  'T' => [ 10 ],
  'J' => [ 10 ],
  'Q' => [ 10 ],
  'K' => [ 10 ],
  'A' => [ 1, 11 ]
}.freeze
```

Where you can then work through all possible combinations of values to arrive at the final results:

```
def hand_value(hand)
  hand.map { |c| CARD_VALUE[c] }.inject([ [ ] ]) do |accum, arr|
    accum.flat_map do |a|
      arr.map do |v|
        a + [ v ]
      end
    end
  end.map(&:sum).uniq
end
```

As in:

```
hand_value(%w[ A T Q ])
# => [21, 31]

hand_value(%w[ A A 2 ])
# => [4, 14, 24]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland ATQ is an amazing Blackjack hand to get, it's 21!

Answer (score 1):

If Ace exists, the index function will return it's index. There's an array method for deleting at a particular index that returns the deleted element. the returned element can then be pushed to the back of the array. All of this can be accomplished in one line, Excuse LoD violations:

```
hand=["heart","spade","Ace","olive", "branch"]

if hand.include?("Ace")
  hand.push(hand.delete_at(hand.index("Ace")))
end

p hand #["heart", "spade", "olive", "branch", "Ace"]
```

NB:only the first 'Ace' will be relocated.

Comment: Note, this won't account for multiple aces.

Comment: Yep, you're right, only the first 'Ace' will be relocated.